# Even after trying all commands found on stackoverflow , it is still showing the following error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am not able to run jupyter notebook even after trying for 2 days ! please help
I am using windows 8.1
[Please click on this for the screen shot of the error while trying to run   jupyter notebook on windows command promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPgs.jpg)

this is the error showing :    Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2

Comment: Copy paste error messages into your question, especially when you can't enter an image inline.

Comment: @Luuklag     this was the error ::      Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2

Comment: What do you not understand in the error message? Did you try `pip install notebook`? What does it return?

Comment: @AndreySobolev   sir ! pip install notebook does not work in mine ! i have to type python -m pip install jupyter  to make it work ! it shows jupyter is there !   but when i try to run jupyter notebook it shows error

Comment: Then you have a broken python installation. The simplest way of making it right would be reinstalling it from scratch. Also you might have another python installed anywhere on your computer

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command on your terminal:

```
pip freeze
```

This will give you a list all the python modules installed.
Check whether jupyter is there in the list or not!

Comment: yes sir ! it shows jupyter is there ::
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.
ipywidgets==7.0.5
jedi==0.11.0
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
mistune==0.8.1
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.2.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.1.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
Pygments==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pyzmq==16.0.3
qtconsole==4.3.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.2